# WinUI 3 XAML Animations

Tags: c#, animation, winui-3

In a WinUi 3 MVVM project I have a media (image and videos) Json list that plays one my one with a certain duration, I am trying to add a fade in and out whenever the image changes, I have tried almost every fontion in but can't get it done, if anyone has done this please let me know how to do it

```xml
<Grid
    x:Name="ImageContainer"
    Visibility="{x:Bind WallpaperViewModel.ImageAnimationVisibility, Mode=OneWay}">
    <Image
        x:Name="WallpaperImage"
        Source="{x:Bind WallpaperViewModel.ImageAccueil, Mode=OneWay}"
        Stretch="UniformToFill"
        Visibility="{x:Bind WallpaperViewModel.ImageWallpaperVisibility, Mode=OneWay}">
        <Image.Triggers>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Image.Loaded">
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <DoubleAnimation
                            AutoReverse="True"
                            BeginTime="0:0:4"
                            Storyboard.TargetName="ImageContainer"
                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                            From="1.0"
                            To="0.0"
                            Duration="0:0:1" />
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger>
        </Image.Triggers>
    </Image>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `Image.Loaded` event is issued when the `Image` control itself is loaded, not every time you the image data is loaded.

This is a simple example using `VisualState`s:

**ViewModel.cs**

```cs
using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.ComponentModel;
using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.Input;
using Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Media.Imaging;
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace AnimationTests;

public partial class ViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    [ObservableProperty]
    private BitmapImage? imageAccueil;

    public event EventHandler<EventArgs>? ImageLoading;

    [RelayCommand(IncludeCancelCommand = true)]
    private async Task Play(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        try
        {
            using PeriodicTimer timer = new(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3));

            while (await timer.WaitForNextTickAsync(cancellationToken) is true)
            {
                ImageLoading?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
                ImageAccueil = new BitmapImage
                {
                    UriSource = new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/StoreLogo.png")
                };
            }
        }
        catch (OperationCanceledException)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

**MainPage.xaml.cs**

```cs
using Microsoft.UI.Xaml;
using Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using System;

namespace AnimationTests;

public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        this.WallpaperViewModel.ImageLoading += this.WallpaperViewModel_ImageLoading;
    }

    private void WallpaperViewModel_ImageLoading(object? sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Forcing to go to "FadeInAndOut" by switching to "Normal" first.
        _ = VisualStateManager.GoToState(this, "Normal", false);
        _ = VisualStateManager.GoToState(this, "FadeInAndOut", false);
    }

    public ViewModel WallpaperViewModel { get; } = new();
}
```

**MainPage.xaml**

```xml
<Page
    x:Class="AnimationTests.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}"
    mc:Ignorable="d">
    <Grid>
        <StackPanel>
            <Button
                Command="{x:Bind WallpaperViewModel.PlayCommand}"
                Content="Play" />
            <Button
                Command="{x:Bind WallpaperViewModel.PlayCancelCommand}"
                Content="Stop" />
            <Grid x:Name="ImageContainer">
                <ContentControl x:Name="WallpaperImagePresenter">
                    <Image
                        x:Name="WallpaperImage"
                        Source="{x:Bind WallpaperViewModel.ImageAccueil, Mode=OneWay}"
                        Stretch="UniformToFill" />
                </ContentControl>
            </Grid>
        </StackPanel>
        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
            <VisualStateGroup>
                <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
                <VisualState x:Name="FadeInAndOut">
                    <Storyboard>
                        <DoubleAnimation
                            AutoReverse="True"
                            Storyboard.TargetName="WallpaperImage"
                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                            From="0.0"
                            To="1.0"
                            Duration="0:0:1.5" />
                    </Storyboard>
                </VisualState>
            </VisualStateGroup>
        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

Comment: Yes but its a mixed list of images and videos and i already have a system timer that changes the to the next media every few seconds depending on the fixed duration of the image of video, so when it the next one is a video it does'nt work correctly.

Comment: my timer                                                                                                                                            
 public async void SetupTimer()
    {
        await CurrentMedia();
        _currentImageIndex = 0;
        _myTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();
        _myTimer.Interval = double.Parse(_wallpapers[_currentImageIndex]["duration"].ToS       tring()) * 1000; // 10 seconds
        _myTimer.Elapsed += OnTimerElapsed;
        _myTimer.Start();
    }

Comment: As I mentioned in my answer, this is an example how you might be able to use ``VisualStates`` to achieve your requirements. You should be able to use your timer to change ``VisualStates``.